# Video stop when play music (spotify for example)

Tags: html, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

In my HTML code the video stops if I play a music at the same time. My code is like the following:

```
<video autoplay id="video-bg" webkit-playsinline loop>
    <source src="videos/login_bg2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="videos/login_bg2.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean it stops other music, like what you have playing in the beackground?

Comment: @mlegg The video stops if I play a music, for example in background... I just would like to show images of the video, because I want to apply a video as background login in my app, but everytime a music is played, the video stops.

Comment: Edit your question and add all of your html there.

Answer (score 0):

Set the AVAudioSession category works for me:

1. Find your AppDelegate.m from Xcode Proj.
2. import the header file: AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h
3. Add below code within the launchOptions {}

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];

My entire code like this:

```js
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];
    
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

NOTE: **withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers** important.